# Inserting a column at the front of a dataframe without a heading in R

Tags: r

I have many csv files that I need to apply a loop to and add to the bottom of the previous added data. Each file requires an additional column for the purposes of identifying that set of data. I.e. a repeated ID of the file name. (When I have completed the loop, I will add column headers.)
All searches I have done add the data using the header. Is it possible to add without?

Dataframe example without loop:

lb1_2015_csv <- "lb1_2015.csv"

lb1_2015 <- read.csv(lb1_2015_csv, header=F, stringsAsFactors = F)

lb1_2015 <- lb1_2015[-c(1:4), -1]
head(lb1_2015)

```
5  2015-01-12 21:00:00 26.664
6  2015-01-12 21:30:00 27.866
7  2015-01-12 22:00:00 27.857
8  2015-01-12 22:30:00 26.111
9  2015-01-12 23:00:00 24.918
10 2015-01-12 23:30:00 26.816
```

Comment: you could add a field like this : `lb1_2015$origin <- lb1_2015_csv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Create a folder in your working directory with all of your .csv files
2. Store them in a list
3. combine into one dataset with `bind_rows`

```
library("dplyr")  
library("readr") 

list_all_csv <- list.files(path = "your path", pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  lapply(read_csv) %>%                                          
  bind_rows                                                      

list_all_csv
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try reading multiple files using `lapply` and add a column with name of the file in it.

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = '\\.csv$', full.names = TRUE)

result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(filenames, function(x) 
          transform(read.csv(x, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
          filename = basename(x))))
```